# How to change the color background of a Context menu?

Tags: android, xml, layout

```
style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

My textcolorprimary is white and the color background of my context menu is white too

Answer (score 0):

The ".menu {" section in gtk.css controls pop-up context menus and menu-bar drop-down menus. You will see the "background-color:" parameter in this section, which you can adjust. But keep in mind there are many other elements within the (context) menu that need to be accounted for, like menu outlines, text colors, buttons, switches, radio buttons, etc., and these may need to be adjusted correspondingly, at various points within the .css file.